# how to remove pairs in a select to itself table

Tags: sql, mysql

I joined a table with it self and I have repeated pairs as I highlighted in the below image how to remove them?

```
select DISTINCT A.name as name1 , B.name as name2
from (select name , ratings.* from reviewers inner join ratings on reviewers.id = 
ratings.reviewer_id ) A ,
(select name , ratings.* from reviewers inner join ratings on reviewers.id = 
ratings.reviewer_id ) B
where A.reviewer_id <> B.reviewer_id 
and A.book_id = B.book_id
order by name1 , name2 ASC
```

| name1 | name2 |
| --- | --- |
| Alice Lewis | Elizabeth Black |
| Chris Thomas | John Smith |
| Chris Thomas | Mike White |
| Elizabeth Black | Alice Lewis |
| Elizabeth Black | Jack Green |
| Jack Green | Elizabeth Black |
| Joe Martinez | Mike Anderson |
| John Smith | Chris Thomas |
| Mike Anderson | Joe Martinez |
| Mike White | Chris Thomas |

Above table used to be an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljkSN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created the DDL and DML statements to reproduce your database and write a query retrieving unrepeated pairs. Here's the "building" code which could be of help to others:

```sql
CREATE TABLE books (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE reviewers (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE ratings (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  reviewer_id INT,
  book_id INT,
  rating INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (reviewer_id) REFERENCES reviewers(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES books(id)
);

-- Inserting sample records
INSERT INTO reviewers (id, name)
VALUES
  (1, 'Alice Lewis'),
  (2, 'Elizabeth Black'),
  (3, 'Chris Thomas'),
  (4, 'John Smith'),
  (5, 'Mike White'),
  (6, 'Jack Green'),
  (7, 'Joe Martinez'),
  (8, 'Mike Anderson');

INSERT INTO books (id, title)
VALUES
  (1, 'The Gulag Archipelago'),
  (2, 'One Day in the Life of Ivan Denisovich'),
  (3, 'Cancer Ward');

-- Insertion of rating records
INSERT INTO ratings (id, reviewer_id, book_id, rating)
VALUES
  (1, 1, 1, 4),
  (2, 1, 2, 3),
  (3, 2, 1, 5),
  (4, 2, 2, 4),
  (5, 2, 3, 2),
  (6, 3, 1, 3),
  (7, 3, 3, 4),
  (8, 4, 1, 2),
  (9, 4, 3, 3),
  (10, 5, 2, 5),
  (11, 6, 1, 1),
  (12, 6, 2, 3),
  (13, 6, 3, 4),
  (14, 7, 1, 3),
  (15, 7, 2, 4),
  (16, 8, 3, 2);
```

And here's the refactored query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  A.name AS name1,
  B.name AS name2
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      reviewers.id,
      reviewers.name,
      ratings.book_id
    FROM
      reviewers
      INNER JOIN ratings ON reviewers.id = ratings.reviewer_id
  ) A
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      reviewers.id,
      reviewers.name,
      ratings.book_id
    FROM
      reviewers
      INNER JOIN ratings ON reviewers.id = ratings.reviewer_id
  ) B ON A.book_id = B.book_id
     AND A.id <> B.id
     AND A.name < B.name
ORDER BY
  name1,
  name2 ASC;
```

The same subquery is used twice with aliases A and B, combining the `reviewers` and `ratings` tables and retrieving the data for each pair of reviewer-book ratings.

The main outer query then selects distinct pairs of reviewer names from the subquery results. We use `JOIN` between the subqueries A and B on 3 conditions:

- `A.book_id = B.book_id` so the pairs of reviewers have rated the same book.
- `A.id <> B.id` to filter out pairs of reviewers that have the same ID, preventing self-matches.
- `A.name < B.name` to ensure that the pairs are ordered consistently like the output below, eliminating repetitions. This way only one combination of names is considered for a given pair, such as "Elizabeth Black-Jack Green" but not "Jack Green-Elizabeth Black".

This is the output you'll get from the refactored query:

```sql
+-----------------+-----------------+
|      name1      |      name2      |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| Alice Lewis     | Chris Thomas    |
| Alice Lewis     | Elizabeth Black |
| Alice Lewis     | Jack Green      |
| Alice Lewis     | Joe Martinez    |
| Alice Lewis     | John Smith      |
| Alice Lewis     | Mike White      |
| Chris Thomas    | Elizabeth Black |
| Chris Thomas    | Jack Green      |
| Chris Thomas    | Joe Martinez    |
| Chris Thomas    | John Smith      |
| Chris Thomas    | Mike Anderson   |
| Elizabeth Black | Jack Green      |
| Elizabeth Black | Joe Martinez    |
| Elizabeth Black | John Smith      |
| Elizabeth Black | Mike Anderson   |
| Elizabeth Black | Mike White      |
| Jack Green      | Joe Martinez    |
| Jack Green      | John Smith      |
| Jack Green      | Mike Anderson   |
| Jack Green      | Mike White      |
| Joe Martinez    | John Smith      |
| Joe Martinez    | Mike White      |
| John Smith      | Mike Anderson   |
+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
select Name1, Name2
from ...
where Name1 < Name2;
```

See [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/FF0CdC6C)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `greatest` and `least` to identify duplicates accross columns :

This query will get duplicates :

```
select greatest(name, name2), least(name, name2)
from mytable
group by greatest(name, name2), least(name, name2)
having count(1) > 1
```

Result :

```
first_name  second_name
Jack Green  Elizabeth Black
```

Then :

```
DELETE t.* FROM mytable t
INNER JOIN (
  select greatest(name, name2) as first_name, least(name, name2) as second_name
  from mytable
  group by greatest(name, name2), least(name, name2)
  having count(1) > 1
) as s ON (t.name = s.first_name and t.name2 = s.second_name)
          OR (t.name2 = s.first_name and t.name = s.second_name)
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/P9zS6FX4)

Answer (score 1):

To remove the duplicates you first need to find them:

```
SELECT 
  LEAST(name1,name2) as L,
  GREATEST(name1,name2) as G
FROM names
GROUP BY LEAST(name1,name2), GREATEST(name1,name2) 
HAVING count(*)>1;
```

Then you can delete them:

```
WITH cte as (
  SELECT 
    LEAST(name1,name2) as L,
    GREATEST(name1,name2) as G
  FROM names
  GROUP BY LEAST(name1,name2), GREATEST(name1,name2) 
  HAVING count(*)>1
)
DELETE FROM names
WHERE (name2,name1) in (select * from cte);
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/96zXaY5o)

Comment: Seems like we have almost same answer :)

Comment: Indeed, I only had problems with "You can't specify target table 'names' for update in FROM clause", which tends to be caused by /me not doing much DELETE statements.... 